Draw Arrow path for Location Based Map navigation Using ARKit iOS
I have indoor map and I want to draw path between two route location ex. from A to B I want to draw ARKit based Arrow path in ios Application. Currently I am using ARAnchor to achieve this but challenges is if A to B is 10 meter and I am adding Nodes on each one meter so instead of 10 different nodes i am getting single Arrow nodes showing all 10 in it. I am using below code.
// Below Code from where I am calling addArpath function
                    if let lat1 = mCurrentPosition?.latitude, let long1 = mCurrentPosition?.longitude {
                        
                        let latEnd = steplocation.latitude
                        let longEnd = steplocation.longitude
                        
                        // if let lastLat  = arrpath.last?.latitude,let lastLong = arrpath.last?.longitude,let lastAltitude = arrpath.last?.altitude{
                        
                        let userLocation = CLLocation(latitude: lat1, longitude: long1)
                        
                        let endLocation = CLLocation(coordinate: CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(CLLocationDegrees(latEnd), CLLocationDegrees(longEnd)), altitude: CLLocationDistance(steplocation.altitude), horizontalAccuracy: CLLocationAccuracy(5), verticalAccuracy: CLLocationAccuracy(0), course: CLLocationDirection(-1), speed: CLLocationSpeed(5), timestamp: Date())
                        
                        let heading = getHeadingForDirectionFromCoordinate(from: userLocation, to: endLocation)

                        let lon1 =  degreesToRadians(long1)     //DegreesToRadians(long1)
                        let lon2 =  degreesToRadians(longEnd);  //DegreesToRadians(longEnd);
                        let lat2 =  degreesToRadians(latEnd);
                        

                        let dLon = lon2 - lon1
            
                        let y = sin(dLon) * cos(lat2);
                        yVal = yVal + y
                        
                       // let distanceToendpoint = calculateDistance(lat: endLocation.coordinate.latitude, long: endLocation.coordinate.longitude)
                        let distvalue =  Int(distance) + Int(pathlength)
                        distance +=  CGFloat(distvalue)
                        
                       
                        for i in stride(from: 0, to: distance, by:1) {
                            print("current loop iteration is:" ,i)
                            let headingValue  = heading - self.heading
                            zValue = zValue + headingValue
                            
                            distanceVal = CGFloat(i) + distanceVal
                            zGlobal = zValue

                    // Calling addARPathtoLocation 

                            addARPathtoLocation(stepLocation:endLocation,zvalue: zValue, yvalue: yVal, distance:Float(i), direction: manuoverType)
                        }
                       
                        //  }
                    }



 // MARK: - ARSessionDelegate
func renderer(_ renderer: SCNSceneRenderer, didAdd node: SCNNode, for anchor: ARAnchor) {
    guard !(anchor is ARPlaneAnchor) else { return }
    let sphereNode = generateArrowNodes(anchor: anchor)
    DispatchQueue.main.async {
        node.addChildNode(sphereNode)
    }
}

//create ARAnchor to add to nodes
func generateArrowNodes(anchor: ARAnchor) -> SCNNode {
    let imageMaterial = SCNMaterial()
    imageMaterial.isDoubleSided = true
    imageMaterial.diffuse.contents = UIImage(named: "blueArrow")
    
    let plane = SCNPlane(width:0.5, height:0.5)
    plane.materials = [imageMaterial]
    plane.firstMaterial?.isDoubleSided = true
    
    let blueNode = SCNNode(geometry: plane)
    blueNode.name = "blueNode"
    blueNode.position = SCNVector3(x:Float(zGlobal), y:0, z:Float(distanceVal))
   
    blueNode.eulerAngles.x  = -.pi / 2
    blueNode.eulerAngles.y -= Float(CGFloat(CGFloat.pi/4*6))
    
    return blueNode
}

func addARPathtoLocation(stepLocation: CLLocation, zvalue: CGFloat, yvalue: CGFloat, distance:Float, direction:VMEManeuverType) {

    // give you the depth of anything ARKit has detected
    
    guard let query = sceneView.raycastQuery(from: sceneView.center , allowing: .estimatedPlane, alignment: .any) else {
        return
    }
    
    let results = sceneView.session.raycast(query)
    guard let hitResult = results.first else {
        print("No surface found")
        return
    }
    
    // Add ARAnchor to Scene
    let anchor = ARAnchor(transform: hitResult.worldTransform)
    sceneView.session.add(anchor: anchor)
}




func radiansToDegrees(_ radians: Double) -> Double {
    return (radians) * (180.0 / Double.pi)
}

func degreesToRadians(_ degrees: Double) -> Double {
    return (degrees) * (Double.pi / 180.0)
}

func getHeadingForDirectionFromCoordinate(from: CLLocation, to: CLLocation) -> Double {
    let fLat = degreesToRadians(from.coordinate.latitude)
    let fLng = degreesToRadians(from.coordinate.longitude)
    let tLat = degreesToRadians(to.coordinate.latitude)
    let tLng = degreesToRadians(to.coordinate.longitude)
    
    let deltaL = tLng - fLng
    
    let x =  sin(deltaL) * cos(tLng) //cos(tLat) * sin(deltaL)
    let y = cos(fLat) * sin(tLat) - sin(fLat) * cos(tLat) * cos(deltaL)
    
    let bearing = atan2(x,y)
    let bearingInDegrees = bearing.toDegrees
    print("Bearing Degrees :",bearingInDegrees) // sanity check
    

   // let degree = radiansToDegrees(atan2(sin(tLng-fLng)*cos(tLat), cos(fLat)*sin(tLat)-sin(fLat)*cos(tLat)*cos(tLng-fLng)))
    
    if bearingInDegrees >= 0 {
        return bearingInDegrees
    } else {
        return bearingInDegrees + 360
    }
}

